# Python very strange for loop issue

Tags: python, for-loop

For some reason, my for loop repeats twice even though it realises that it should only repeat from 0 to 1. My code is intended to take a guess from the user, see whether that letter is in the word and then return a string with your guess in the right position in the word. Now the problem I am having is with multiple occurances of the letter. It works when the letter appears twice but when the letter appears a second time, the letter is firstly placed in the correct position but also placed at the very last position of the string. I have no idea why this is.

```
import random
UsedLetters = []
RandomWord = "letter" #random.choice(open("GuessTheWord.txt").readlines())[:-1]
WordList = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"]
Try = 1
while Try < 11:
    print("Try", Try, "/10")
    Guess = input("Please enter your guess").lower()
    if Guess.isalpha() and Guess not in UsedLetters and len(Guess) == 1:
        UsedLetters.append(Guess)
        FakeWord = RandomWord
        if Guess in RandomWord:
            for x in (RandomWord.count(Guess)-1):
                print(RandomWord.count(Guess))
                WordList[FakeWord.find(Guess) + x] = Guess
                FakeWord = FakeWord.replace(Guess, "", 1)
            Word = ''.join(WordList)
            print(Word)
            if Word == RandomWord:
                print("You won the game!")
                break
        else:
            print("That guess is not in the word. Next try.")
            Try+=1
    elif Guess in UsedLetters:
        print("You have already used that letter.")
    else:
        print("Guess is not 1 letter.")
if Try == 11:
    print("You lost try again next time!")
```

I am genuinenely so confused.

PS, it would be much appreciated if you could keep the whole process the exact same amount of lines or shorter as I came up with a solution to the problem that was shorter than my friends and I would like to keep it that way. ; )

Comment: Also, I know that there should be a 0 in the for loop but I removed that for testing and forgot to put it back in before uploading this post so I know that's not the problem.

Comment: You should use `this_format` for python variables.  `CapWords` is used for classes.

Comment: `for x in (RandomWord.count(Guess)-1):` This will return a single count. How to loop through this? Forgot to use`range()`?

Comment: @user2695448 It would actually be an error, absent a comma, because an `int` isn't iterable.

Comment: @chepner `range(5)` will be treated as `range(0,5)` and it is iterable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try replacing your for loop with this:

```
for x in range(0, RandomWord.count(Guess)):
  print(RandomWord.count(Guess))
  WordList[FakeWord.find(Guess)] = Guess
  FakeWord = FakeWord.replace(Guess, "*", 1)
```

I changed the for loop condition because an integer cannot be a range for iteration. Also, you have to replace the letter with some placeholder character. Why? Because if you put "", the string is shortened by 1 and the next character will be in the same index. For example, when you type in 't', first t is at index 2 and second t at 3. After replacement with ""
letter would become leter and the second t is now at index 2. **So you do not want to change the length of the string**